# A simple bar chart of the populations of the countries of the world with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, data-visualization

All I'd like to do is make a simple barchart of the populations of the countries of the world.

Ideally, the x-axis would have country names, small font, but slanting diagonally; the y-axis would be logarithmic.

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['Rank', 'Country', 'UN_Continental_region', 'UN_Statistical_region', 'Population', 'Population2015', 'percent_change']

pop_list = pd.read_table('country.dat', names=cols)

pop_list['Population'].plot().hist(alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The plot().hist line gives a TypeError: hist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x' 
error, but then a the plt.show() doe make a line plot of the populations.

What's going on???!!

The full code can be found here:
https://github.com/d80b2t/python/blob/master/wealth_and_population/population_barchart_forStackOverflow.ipynb

Comment: I don't think you want a histogram at all.  A histogram will bin the data, but your data is already binned, with a separate population number for each country.  You just want a bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a `TypeError` is that you are calling `plot().hist()` when you should be calling `plot.hist()` (note the lack of parentheses after `plot`).

The `DataFrame.plot` object, without parentheses, is a pandas plot API instance, which has a `hist()` method that references the associated dataframe. When you *call* that plot API object itself with `DataFrame.plot()`, it returns a matplotlib axis instance, which has a `hist()` method that requires an array as the first argument (it's the normal `ax.hist()` method that you might be familiar with from matplotlib).

The reason the plot still shows up is that when you do `pop_list.plot()`, it creates a line graph. It's not until you call the `hist()` method of that axis that you get the error... you've already created the plot!

So, to get rid of the type error, use

```
pop_list.plot.hist()
```

But fixing that will give you a histogram of populations, and it sounds like you want a *bar chart*, not a histogram. To create a bar chart, you can use `pop_list.plot.bar`. This is something like what you want:

```
pop_list.plot.bar('Country', 'Population')
```

But there are so many countries in your data that the chart is too busy to be very useful.